# Копирование из одного массива в другой

Tags: javascript, массивы

Используя методы массива slice() и splice() нужно скопировать один массив в другой.

```
let arr1 = [1,2,3];
let arr2 = [4,5];
```

Нужно вернуть `[4, 1, 2, 3, 5]`. Нету идей на счёт этого.

Comment: `arr2.splice(1,0,...arr2)`

Comment: @Grundy я тоже так подумал, но как сюда slice() воткнуть

Comment: @splash58, можно куда угодно, скорее всего после arr2, чтобы его не менять

Answer (score 2):

Как уже упомянули в комментариях. По сути `slice()` нам даже и не надо.

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
let arr2 = [4, 5];

arr2.splice(1, 0, ...arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score -1):

Если я правильно понял, то надо смешать два массива, тогда вот так:

```
let arr = arr1.concat(arr2);
```

Весь код:

```js
let arr1 = [1,2,3];
let arr2 = [3,4];

let arr = arr1.concat(arr2);

alert(arr);
```

Comment: _Нужно вернуть `[4, 1, 2, 3, 5]`_

Comment: @Grundy он мб ошибся. А так странно как-то))

Comment: @Grundy ааа)) Надо типо вставить именно в середину. Ну gg